# At what point am I using too much memory on a Mac?

Tags: python, macos, memory

I've tried really hard to figure out why my python is using 8 gigs of memory.  I've even use `gc.get_object()` and measured the size of each object and only one of them was larger than 10 megs.  Still, all of the objects, and there were about 100,000 of them, added up to 5.5 gigs.  On the other hand, my computer is working fine, and the program is running at a reasonable speed.  So is the fact that I'm using so much memory cause for concern?[image]

Comment: Please provide the code you are running in python. Alternatively,  you can force the Garbage Collector to release unreferenced memory with gc.collect()

Comment: I would love to show the code, but it's too big and it uses 90,000 saved files.  I've given up on that problem for now.  The program works at a reasonable speed so I've put that problem low on my list of priorities.

Comment: I don't feel that this is a good question for SO. It's not exactly "opinioned-based", but it doesn't seem like it has a real answer. You're using "too much" memory when it is either not possible to run your program, or not feasible to do so without too great an impact on other programs or without undue cost. That being said, using 8G on a 16G machine is fine, in that the OS won't kill your program for misbehaving.

Comment: But there is two programs running at 8GB.  This is because when you fork  a program it runs several times faster and you need at least two forks.

Comment: As for the charge 'this doesn't have a real answer', that's not true because the answer is either: 'yes, it's ok to run a Mac with this much memory' or 'no'.

Comment: It doesn't have a real answer. "'yes, it's ok to run a Mac with this much memory' or 'no'" can't be stated with the knowledge given. Is 8GB a lot of memory for a full resolution 4k After Effects render? Probably not. Is it a lot of memory for an iOS fart app? Almost certainly yes.

Answer (score 2):

As @bnaecker said this doesn't have a simple (i.e., yes/no) answer. It's only a problem if the combined RSS (resident set size) of all running processes exceeds the available memory thus causing excessive demand paging.

You didn't say how you calculated the size of each object. Hopefully it was by using `sys.getsizeof()` which should accurately include the overhead associated with each object. If you used some other method (such as calling the `__sizeof()` method directly) then your answer will be far lower than the correct value. However, even `sys.getsizeof()` won't account for wasted space due to memory alignment. For example, consider this experiment (using python 3.6 on macOS):

```
In [25]: x='x'*8193

In [26]: sys.getsizeof(x)
Out[26]: 8242

In [28]: 8242/4
Out[28]: 2060.5
```

Notice that last value. It implies that the object is using 2060 and 1/2 words of memory. Which is wrong since all allocations consume a multiple of a word. In fact, it looks to me like `sys.getsizeof()` does not correctly account for word alignment and padding of either the underlying object or the data structure that describes the object. Which means the value is smaller than the amount of memory actually used by the object. Multiplied by 100,000 objects that could represent a substantial amount of memory.

Also, many memory allocators will round up large allocations to a page size (typically a multiple of 4 KiB). Which results in "wasted" space that is probably not going to be included in the `sys.getsizeof()` return value.

Comment: thanks for the info.  I really appreciate that.  And yes I was using sys.getsizeof()

Comment: @ kylefoley76 Note that I only scratched the surface of this topic. Your question falls in the broad category of "performance tuning". An incredibly complex topic even when limited to a specific OS (e.g., macOS) and language (e.g., Python). It's something customers would pay upwards of $200/hour for my expertise when I did such work two decades ago.